# Laser beam max distance at 30000 ft

Tags: optics, laser, atmospheric-science, geometric-optics

would the max  the distance covered by a green pointer at 30000 feet above ground level be much greater than same laser pointed on earth surface? for example if the manufacturer claims max distance of one KM on ground level would the same laser reach 10 KM at 30000 feet above ground (because of thinner air lower impurities etc)?

Answer (score 0):

The range might be greater because there may be less absorption by the air and the particles in the air but the spreading out of the laser beam because it is not parallel would probably have a large effect so reducing your estimated distance by a considerable amount.

If you increase the distance by a factor of ten then the light will be spread over an area $10^2=100$ times as large.

Shine a laser pointer over a distance of 10 m and then 100 m to observe how the width of the beam increases with distance.

This article on [lunar laser ranging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment) might be of interest in that it shows that even with the laser used to make these measurements there is beam spreading.

Comment: "even with a very high quality laser there is beam spreading" Actually, the diverge (spreading) of a laser beam is not a matter of quality. It is simply determined by the size of the beam and its wavelength. Beam divergence angle = wavelength/beamradius/pi.

Comment: @flippiefanus Thanks for your comment.  I think that the cheap laser pointers that I have bought have a beam width which is determined by diffraction and that is why I made the comparison.  I have edited out the reference to high quality in my answer.